How do I get my Cloudfront distro to serve my API Gateway endpoint on /api
I have an API Gateway that I can connect to either from the API Gateway granted url or a custom subdomain of my main domain. Ideally though, I would like to route it through the Cloudfront distro which is served on my main domain. When I try this, I get a 'Forbidden' response.
I have set up an origin to my Cloudfront which points to my API Gateway endpoint (stage 'prod'). I have tried both with and without the origin path '/prod'. I'm setting the behaviour path to '/api/*'. When I connect on https://example.com/api/ (or https://example.com/api/prod/ depending on origin path), I get a response with {"message":"Forbidden"} rather than my api.
I've seen other questions on SO pertaining to a similar setup but with a Custom Domain for API Gateway. I tried setting up a Custom Domain but it didn't get me any further. Based on my understanding, Custom Domain would not be the correct approach for this, since it automatically creates a CloudFront distro behind the scenes whereas I'll be using my existing CloudFront
